# django - remove field name and brackets

Tags: django

I have the following queryset -

```
pk = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('database1').extra(where=['jobmst_alias=%s'], params=[alias]).values('jobmst_id')
```

Which returns the following -

```
[{'jobmst_id': 21195}]
```

edit -

```
pk = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('database1').extra(where=['jobmst_alias=%s'], params=[alias]).values_list('jobmst_id', flat=True)
```

Returns the following -

```
[21195]
```

Close but I don't want the brackets I want only the integer.

I want it to simply give me the integer value so I can call it in another query -

```
mst = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('database1').raw("""
    SELECT jobmst_id, jobmst_type, jobmst_prntname AS jobmst_prntid, jobmst_active,
    evntmst_id, jobmst_evntoffset, jobmst_name, jobmst_mode, jobmst_owner, jobmst_desc,
    jobmst_crttm, jobdtl_id, jobmst_lstchgtm, jobmst_runbook, jobcls_id, jobmst_prntname,
    jobmst_alias, jobmst_dirty FROM Jobmst WHERE jobmst_id = %s""", [pk])
```

Which would ideally parse as this -

```
mst = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('database1').raw("""
    SELECT jobmst_id, jobmst_type, jobmst_prntname AS jobmst_prntid, jobmst_active,
    evntmst_id, jobmst_evntoffset, jobmst_name, jobmst_mode, jobmst_owner, jobmst_desc,
    jobmst_crttm, jobdtl_id, jobmst_lstchgtm, jobmst_runbook, jobcls_id, jobmst_prntname,
    jobmst_alias, jobmst_dirty FROM Jobmst WHERE jobmst_id = 21195""")
```

Comment: how about `qs.values_list('jobmst_id', flat=True)`?

Comment: so close!  It's returning the value as [21195] those square brackets are killing it in my query I want to run it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` returns list of dicts, so you can access value by list index and key name:

```
try:
    pk = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('database1').extra(where=['jobmst_alias=%s'],
        params=[alias]).values('jobmst_id')[0]['jobmst_id']
except IndexError:
    pk = None
```

You can use `values_list` that returns only list of specified fields values and to access the value you need only index:

```
try:
    pk = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('database1').extra(where=['jobmst_alias=%s'],
        params=[alias]).values_list('jobmst_id', flat=True)[0]
except IndexError:
    pk = None
```

Comment: You probably want to put the second example in a try/except IndexError code block to avoid runtime errors if the return value is an empty list.

Comment: @JeffBauer try/except is needed, im agree

Comment: The first one did it thanks!  I'm assuming this would be the case with any field I want to return?  .values('field')[0]['field']